# SassError: Positional arguments must come before keyword arguments

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material

I have a `mixin` defined like this:

```
@mixin el-light-theme($default: false, $typography:null) { ... }
```

This mixin delegates to a function defined like this:

```
@function el-create-theme(
  $primary,
  $accent,
  $warn: mat.define-palette(mat.$orange-palette),
  $success: mat.define-palette(mat.$green-palette),
  $danger: mat.define-palette(mat.$red-palette),
  $info: mat.define-palette(mat.$teal-palette),
  $create-light-theme: true,
  $typography: null
) { ... }
```

And it seems like the compiler does not like the `$typography: null` argument at the end.

The build produces this error:

```
HookWebpackError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Positional arguments must come before keyword arguments.
   ╷
18 │     $typography
```

My interpretation of it is that SASS considers `$typography:null` to be a 'positional' argument, rather than a keyword argument, since it's assigned a default value of null, and since this is the case, it has to come before the other 'keyword' arguments that have none null values for initialization.

I've tried this out as well, and it compiles without error, so just wanted to confirm whether my interpretation is correct?